# One Class SVM for time series data

Tags: time-series, svm

One CLass SVM is a well known machine learning algorithm for novality detection, but it is applicable only for a set of vectors not for time series data.

I read a paper recently of how to use (One-Class SVM) OCSVM with time series data by first converting the time series into a phase space then apply the projection into OCSVM [1]

Is there an implementation or library for such an algorithm to handle OCSVM with time series data?

[1] http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.653.2440&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Paper is behind a paywall?

Comment: @Hobbes I updated the link to a public one